# Print a "counter" (1 to 3) with 5 numbers in a line. And on the next line start on the last number of the previous line

Tags: python

I just want to print something like that:

1, 2, 3, 1, 2

3, 1, 2, 3, 1

2, 3, 1, 2, 3

and keep going like this (not just 3 or 4 lines)

In other words, I want to print 5 numbers in a line that goes from 1 to 3 and when jumping to the next line it needs to start from the last printed number but always in that 1 to 3 range.
I know its really simple and probably obvious but I can't figure out how to make it lol

```
x = [1,2,3,1,2]
c = 0
for i in range(20): 
  print(x[c],x[c+1],x[c+2],x[c],x[c+1])
```

or

```
x = 1
for i in range(20): 
  print(x,x+1,x+2,x,x+1)
```

and tried this one as well

```
x = 1
for i in range(10):
  for x in [1,2,3]:
    if x == 3:
      x = 1      
   print(x,x+1,x+2)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm trying several things. Like this (I'll edit the main post)

Comment: This question is hard to understand. In what sense does `1, 2, 3, 1, 2` "go from 1 to 3" and how after printing that does `3, 1, 2, 3, 1` "start from the last printed number" given the last printed number was `2`?

Comment: Hint: you want `[1, 2, 3] * 5`, but broken into three parts.

Comment: @Amadan ah! that makes sense now.

Comment: @mark Sorry. I'll try to explain better. English is not my native language and I'm tired. The idea is to print a line with 5 numbers (those numbers go from 1 to 3, so like a counter with 3 being the highest number and the resetting to 1). Then when going to the next line, it starts with the last number printed on the previous line.

Comment: Do you know about the modulo `%` operator? It will help greatly here. What you're doing is just counting modulo 3.

Comment: @Amadan thank you. I'll try a bit more with your suggestion

Comment: @smci I've just read about it. Gonna try with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the most amazing things about python is the exceptional standard library that is built in and include [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

This makes things like this really memory efficient and easy to read. `cycle()` sets up and iterator that just keeps yielding 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3... over and over. `islice()` takes a certain number from that iterator:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

nums = cycle([1,2,3])

for r in range(3):
    print(*islice(nums, 5), sep=',')
```

This prints:

```
1,2,3,1,2
3,1,2,3,1
2,3,1,2,3
```

This is probably not what you were imagining, but learning itertools will save a bunch of time in the end and it's one of the nice touches that make python so readable and such a pleasure to use.

Answer (score 0):

There are more succinct (and trickier) ways to do this with `range`, but here's how to do it with a single counter that's incremented through a nested loop:

```
>>> x = 0
>>> for _ in range(3):
...     a = []
...     for _ in range(5):
...         x = x % 3 + 1
...         a.append(x)
...     print(", ".join(map(str, a)))
...
1, 2, 3, 1, 2
3, 1, 2, 3, 1
2, 3, 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: Thank you. Gonna experiment a bit with this code. I don't know some of this stuff yet like "map" and I'm just learning how to mess with lists

Comment: The `join` and `map` are just to make it easier to print a comma-separated list without having to do special stuff to remove a trailing comma.  If you're not picky about that, you could get rid of `a` and instead of `a.append(x)` do something like `print(x, end=", ")`, with a `print()` in the outer loop to add linebreaks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it. You can generate the whole sequence, then break it up:

```
seq = [1, 2, 3] * 5
for subseq in [seq[i : i + 5] for i in range(0, len(seq), 5)]:
    print(', '.join(str(el) for el in subseq))
```

Or you can count up, and use modulo to bring everything into the desired range, breaking when appropriate:

```
for i in range(15):
    print((i % 3) + 1, end=", " if (i + 1) % 5 else "\n")
```

Comment: Thank you!

The second one I think I've understood everything (I just didn't know about this "end" parameter, very useful).

As for the first one, its a bit confusing yet. Specially the "[seq[i : i + 5]", I've realized that this is controlling how many numbers its printing but I didn't understand the ":".

Comment: Then to explain the first: first see what `[1, 2, 3] * 5` does. `range(0, 15, 5)` will count from 0 to 15 in steps of 5, generating 0, 5 and 10. `seq[0 : 5]` will give you five elements starting from 0th and ending just before 5th, `seq[5 : 10]` the next 5 elements (from 5th to just before 10th), and `seq[10 : 15]` the last five.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, counting modulo 3:

```
N = 3
for row in range(N):
    print([(row + col)%3 + 1 for col in range(5)], sep=',')
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
[2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
... # just increase N to whatever desired value
```